# Figuring Out What 'providerPackageName' means in Health Connect Documentation

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to figure out how to use the Health Connect API using the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect/get-started) since apparently the [Google Fit API has been deprecated and will be discontinued in a year](https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect-guidelines/migrate/migration-guide).

However, I am stuck on [Step 2 part 2](https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect/get-started#step-2), specifically when the code makes use of something called a `providerPackageName` in this code snippet:

```
val availabilityStatus = HealthConnectClient.sdkStatus(context, providerPackageName)
if (availabilityStatus == HealthConnectClient.SDK_UNAVAILABLE) {
  return // early return as there is no viable integration
}
if (availabilityStatus == HealthConnectClient.SDK_UNAVAILABLE_PROVIDER_UPDATE_REQUIRED) {
  // Optionally redirect to package installer to find a provider, for example:
  val uriString = "market://details?id=$providerPackageName&url=healthconnect%3A%2F%2Fonboarding"
  context.startActivity(
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
      setPackage("com.android.vending")
      data = Uri.parse(uriString)
      putExtra("overlay", true)
      putExtra("callerId", context.packageName)
    }
  )
  return
}
val healthConnectClient = HealthConnectClient.getOrCreate(context)
// Issue operations with healthConnectClient
```

From what little I can gather from the documentation, it says that it is "optional package provider to choose for backend implementation", but I have absolutely no idea how this is used or what it actually means. There is no example I was able to search for that made use of this parameter, so can someone please explain how I can use this variable? Is it supposed to be the package name of the health app of choice?

For context I am basically relearning Android development to develop an app for a startup, with one of the requirements of the app being the ability to read heart rate data in real-time. So I am probably missing some obvious beginner concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Provider package name is nothing but the package name of the Google Health Connect app, which happens to be `com.google.android.apps.healthdata`.

Answer (score 3):

It is the package name of the app that you are requesting data from. [Source](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:health/connect/connect-client/src/main/java/androidx/health/connect/client/HealthConnectClient.kt;l=313?q=sdkStatus) . The current default value is `com.google.android.apps.healthdata`

Right now this parameter doesn't make sense as the health connect api is powered by the HealthConnect sdk / app.I believe this parameter is to allow data supply from other providers bypassing the health connect api's incase if Google wants to do this in future.

Comment: Thanks for the source and potential reasoning.